# Can jdbi be spring dao bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbi

How to register DAO class extended from [JDBI](http://www.jdbi.org/) abstract class as Spring bean? I wanna use JDBI + Spring JdbcTemplate + Spring Transactions together

Comment: Have you looked at the DBIFactoryBean https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/src/main/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/spring/DBIFactoryBean.java

I haven't played with JDBI for quite a while but their factory class should support participating in Spring managed transactions. There is a config example here - https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/skife/jdbi/v2/spring/test-context.xml

Comment: Pls check it - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jdbi/spring/jdbi/B_jQ89Au970/VHBG-g9eqpUJ - DBIFactoryBean `was written, oh,
6-7 years ago and I haven't used it in, oh, 6-7 years`. Also this thread provides instructions to configure DBI with Spring transaction management. We will try it.